# Best practices for image res / pixel size in hybrid mobile apps for ios and android?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

What are best practices for image res / pixel size for full screen images in hybrid (Ionic and React Native) apps for both ios and android? How do you handle the different screen sizes? Do you produce different images for different screens as you might do for web? Or do you go with one image size and then how do you handle the issues that arise with that? What are the pixel sizes you work with?

Thank you.

Comment: do you  mean image adjusting for different devices?

Comment: Hello Sa E, yes exactly.

Comment: if that is the requirement of your u can chive by a directive which reads device screen width and adjusts our image div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through this directive i overcame the image stretching issue in Tinder profile kind app

```
app.directive('resize', function ($window) {

    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {

            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w-30;

            scope.style = function () {
                return {
                    'height': (newValue.h - 100) + 'px',
                    'width': (newValue.w - 100) + 'px'
                };
            };

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
```